# At what stage does combat actually start?

Tags: fury-of-dracula

(Question based on the third edition)

A couple of combat scenarios had us a little confused.

Scenario 1:

```
Day starts
Player 1 moves into city where Dracula currently is.

Does combat start immediately?
Even though Player 2 would be able to get into that city during their move?
```

Scenario 2:

```
Night starts
There are 2 hunters in the same city with Dracula.
Player 1 needs to take an action.

Does combat start immediately?
```

Comment: That's two questions.  Please ask them separately so that any answers can be voted on appropriately.

Comment: The question boils down to "does combat start immediately".  I could have phrased it differently for sure and I appreciate your comment.  I feel an edit or just the suggestion would've sufficed and that a downvote is rather unnecessary though, especially to a first time question.  The question isn't that bad and we don't exactly want to scare people away from asking things, do we?

Comment: Is it for 3rd edition?

Comment: Yes.  I will add that to the tags.  I already have the answer but will accept yours if you add it.

Comment: Also, scenario 2 mentions "evening" what do you mean in game terms? Dusk? Nught?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you ask about 3rd edition rules. From rules reference:

> If a hunter is on Dracula’s current location during dawn or dusk, he
>   must start a combat with Dracula.

And also:

> Dawn occurs before day, and dusk occurs before night.

So, combat with Dracula only happens between action phases, not immediately.

EDIT:
To clarify your scenarious:

Scenario 1: Other Hunters continue to do their actions for this phase, then combat occurs. Since movement normally only allowed during the Day, I assume combat would happen at Dusk, and night effects on combat cards would apply.

Scenario 2: Since it's just beginning of the Night, it means that combat at Dusk has just concluded (for described situation to arise Dracula already was in the city when Hunters moved in during the Day). So all Hunters carry on their actions. THEN it's Dracula's move, and if Dracula stays in the same city with Hunters or moves to city with another Hunter, combat at Dawn occurs.

Comment: Would this answer change if it was talking about a different edition of the rules?

Comment: @JoeW AFAIK combat in previous editions is very different, so I assume, this answer is only applicable for 3rd edition. OP confirmed that question referes to 3rd ed. in the comments